# Let $PSL(3,q)$, $q$ odd. Then for $p \mid q(q^2 - 1)$ and $s \mid q-1$ ($p,s$ prime) we have a $p$-subgroup $X\ne 1$ such that $s$ divides $|N_G(X)|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, finite-groups, lie-groups

Let $G = PSL(3, q)$ with $q$ odd, the projective special linear group over a finite field of order $q$. Let $p, s$ be prime numbers. If $p$ divides $q(q^2 - 1)$ and $s$ divides $q-1$, then there exists a nontrivial $p$-subgroup $X \le G$ (i.e. a subgroup whose order is a power of $p$) such that $s$ divides $|N_G(X)|$.

> Why is this so and where does these subgroups come from?

This occurs in an argument of a proof, but I do not see it. Just as a note, we have
$$
 |G| = \frac{(q^3 - 1)(q^3-q)q^2}{\gcd(q-1,3)}.
$$

Comment: See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1657057/if-psl-22k-acts-on-odd-set-such-that-mboxfixg-le-3-for-g-ne-1-t).

Comment: Why do you think they are related? I do not see a connection (except that they are both from me, and of course come from a related domain). I do not see that one solves the other. Also the other question is more specific.

Comment: They are both on $PSL(2,q)$, both concerned with group actions, both with the normalizer $N_G(X)$, but different questions. People interested in this question may also have a look at the other question - or don't you want this ?

Comment: Oh, yes of course :) I thought you wanted in some way say that this question is redundant. But yes, someone who might answer this might also be competent in answering the other question of mine. PS: This one is on $PSL(3,q) \ne PSL(2,q)$ (oh, I wrote this wrongly in the caption, fixed)!

Comment: I see, but this was different $1$ minute ago ? Do you have to change also $p\mid q(q^2-1)$ ?

Comment: It is false, for example in ${\rm PSL}(3,13)$ with $p=7$ and $s=3$.

Comment: Ok. No $p\mid q(q^2-1)$ is meant as written. Okay, this comes from a paper. They put the additional restriction that $G$ acts transitive such that $|\mbox{fix}(g)| \le 3$ and $p \in \pi(G_{\alpha})$, but I thought that might hold without that.